# Auto Reconnect VPN on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

I am currently connecting to the internet through a tethered connection to my mobile data network. To get around the mobile network providers insistence that I should pay them extra to use the same service through a different device, I am also using a VPN to actually connect to the internet. Naturally, network signal may easily drop at times and disrupt the connection, and this disconnects the VPN, even though the tethered connection itself never actually disconnects.

A great example of my problem can ironically be found on the following Microsoft Technet page regarding a wonderous solution, for Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637830(v=ws.10).aspx

> For example, consider a user traveling to work on a train. To make the most out of her time, she uses a wireless mobile broadband card to connect to the Internet and then establishes a VPN connection to her company’s network. As the train passes through a tunnel, she loses her Internet connection. Once outside of the tunnel, the wireless mobile broadband card automatically reconnects to the Internet. However, with earlier versions of Windows, the VPN does not reconnect, and she needs to repeat the multi-step process of connecting to the VPN. This can quickly become time consuming for mobile users with intermittent connectivity.

I cannot find any trace of this feature on Windows 10 however, nor anything like it. Is there any way to either have the VPN connection always attempt to reconnect until I explicitly disconnect (like the 'Connect automatically' option on normal networks) or simply stay alive so it can resume once the network connectivity comes back?

Comment: yes there is, but it depends on the kind of VPN you are using. We shall need more details.

Comment: I wasn't really aware there were multiple kinds, just that I connect using the 'PTPP' method but there are plenty of other options, it just seems easiest.

Comment: For the  case, I suggest you take a look at [SoftEther VPN](https://www.softether.org/) or [Tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks [@Michael Sticlaru](https://superuser.com/users/868461/michael-sticlaru). Now I'm using this application [AutoVPNConnect](https://sourceforge.net/projects/autovpnconnect/) for Windows 10.

I turned off the network on my PC and the VPN was closed. Then connected to WiFi. And after 3 seconds the VPN will connect "by itself". But don't close AutoVPNConnect. Make sure the application icon is in the tray.

> - It`s free application
> - Supported: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10
> - Every VPN connection created with the Windows built in VPN client is
>   supported
> - This tool can connect to your VPN when starting Windows
> - Work in background

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Look like autoreconnect feature is missing from Windows 10 VPN.

There is however an open source app that does that: https://sourceforge.net/projects/autovpnconnect/

Comment: While recommending software please follow [this general outline](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690), otherwise our link-only answer may be considered low quality.

Answer (score -2):

You can just create a task for this in task scheduler.

Create a bat file with a link to your vpn connection.

Add the appropriate connection information.

Open task scheduler and create a new task, setup the appropriate triggers and link the action to your batch file.

Comment: Can you describe “the appropriate triggers” to detect VPN disconnection, in detail?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.